# Select four teams of 9 from 36

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling to understand a type of combinatorics problem where we are dealing with multiple groupings. Through applying another example, I've come up with the following but I don't fully understand why...

The gym teacher must make up four volleyball teams of $9$ girls each from the $36$ freshman girls in her P.E. class. In how many ways can she select these four teams? Call the teams $A, B, C$ and $D$.

$${36 \choose 9}_{\text{teamA}}*{27 \choose 9}_{\text{teamB}}*{18 \choose 9}_{\text{teamC}}*{\dbinom{9}{9}}_{\text{teamD}}*{1 \over 4!}_{\text{num Teams}}$$

I believe that the last term takes care of the fact that order doesn't matter in the teams themselves.

I would greatly appreciate any explanation or validation that I'm thinking about this the correct way.

Comment: I gave an answer but I want to clarify something. Does the problem label the teams or did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the teams are labeled in the statement of the problem the order actually does matter. The answer in that case can be written as
$$\binom{36}{9,9,9,9}=\frac{36!}{(9!)^4}$$
which uses the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

If the teams are not labeled, then your reasoning is correct, and the answer is also equal to
$$\frac{1}{4!}\binom{36}{9,9,9,9}=\frac{36!}{4!(9!)^4}$$